# $T(X)=AX-XA$, prove that $\ker(T)=V$ if and only if $A$ is a scalar matrix, i.e., $A=\alpha I$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=R^{n\times n}$,  $T:V\to V$, $T(X)=AX-XA$. Prove that $\ker(T)=V$ if and only if $A$ is a scalar matrix, i.e., $A=\alpha I$.

Comment: **Hint**: Plug in the matrices $E_{ij}$ with only one non-zeros entry, a 1 at position $(i,j)$.

Comment: Saying that $\ker(T)=V$ is the same as saying that $AX=XA$ for all $n\times n$ matrices $X$. Now use particular matrices; for instance those that have all zero entries except for $1$ in position $(i,j)$.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I have done the thing you told me: plug a matrix that has all zero entries except for 1 in position $(i,j)$,and I have the result that $a_{ii}=a_{jj}$. So the $\alpha$ will be the entry in diagonal?

Comment: Hi, I also have another subquestion. Prove that if $n\ge 2$, then $kernel(T)$ always contains at least two independent vectors.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105040/centralizer-of-a-matrix-over-a-finite-field Look at the second answer. This map always has kernel dimension $\geq n$, and equality holds if and only if the characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial for $A$ coincide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix with a $1$ at the $(i,j)$-th entry and zero elsewhere. The usual proof is to note that for $i\neq j$,

- the $(i,j)$-th entry of $AE_{jj}-E_{jj}A$ is $a_{ij}$,
- the $(i,j)$-th entry of $AE_{ij}-E_{ij}A$ is $a_{ii}-a_{jj}$.

Alternatively, you may first show that $A$ is a diagonal matrix by considering a diagonal matrix $X=D$ with distinct diagonal entries, and then show that $A$ is a scalar matrix by considering the matrix $X=J$ with all entries equal to $1$. This more or less is the same as the previous proof, but easier for mental calculation. However, modification is needed if the underlying field is finite, because there may not exist a diagonal matrix $D$ with distinct diagonal entries. Consequently this proof may becomes more complicated that the previous one.

If you know Kronecker product, the easiest proof is to consider the equation $I\otimes A-A^T\otimes I=0$. By comparing the first diagonal blocks on both sides, we immediately obtain $A=a_{11}I$.